# error 503 ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC while deploying to Appservice

Tags: azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-503

- **Deploying to**: Azure App Service
  **Deployment method:** webdeploy
  **Deploying:** WebJob
  **App service :** Available & started
  **Deployment status:** Files are added/deployed into the azure app service.

Solution: Retrigger the deployment after 2 mins. It does work.

But trying to find out the reason for the failure.
Please let me know if there are any leads.

[image: Refer to the image for the deployment log]